# How to disable pinch-to-zoom in Firefox on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, touchpad, zoom, synaptics-touchpad

When trying to scroll in Firefox using my trackpad, I end up accidentally changing the page's zoom level.

On other OSes you can disable pinch-to-zoom by going to `about:config` and blanking out `browser.gesture.pinch.in` and `browser.gesture.pinch.out`, but that solution doesn't work on Windows 10.

How does one disable pinch-to-zoom in Firefox on Windows?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but since you mentioned Synaptics touchpad in the tags, have you checked your touchpad driver settings to see if there's an option for pinching in there?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done from Windows 10 settings app. After disabling `browser.gesture.pinch.in` and `browser.gesture.pinch.out` from `about:config`, go to Settings > Devices > Touchpad and uncheck 'Pinch to zoom' option. Note that this may also disable pinch to zoom feature for the other applications.

You can also simply use Ctrl+Scroll to zoom in-out in web pages instead of using pinch to zoom.